# Is it possible to use readline instead of libedit in Python's raw_input under OS X?

Tags: python, macos, readline

From [the readline module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html), it mentions:

> On MacOS X the readline module can be implemented using the libedit library instead of GNU readline. The configuration file for libedit is different from that of GNU readline.

Is it possible to use the readline library in `/usr/lib/libreadline.dylib` for example, or even compiled with MacPorts or Homebrew?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sudo easy_install readline
```

Comment: If you use easy_install instead of pip, it will download the binary egg and work without having to modify your PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use GNU `readline` from MacPorts or elsewhere when building Python by specifying the additional library and include files when invoking the `configure` script. See the python installer build script in the Python source tree (`Mac/BuildScript/build-installer.py`) for an example.  It builds a local copy of GNU `readline` when building for targets of 10.4 or earlier.

Keep in mind that on current OS X releases, `/usr/lib/libreadline.dylib` is merely a symlink to `libedit`; AFAIK, Apple does not ship GNU `readline` as a library in OS X:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libreadline.dylib 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  15 Sep  5  2009 /usr/lib/libreadline.dylib@ -> libedit.2.dylib
```